# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. if (i%2==0):

Tags: python, encryption

```
  def encrypted(message):
    encrypted=' '
    for i in message:
        if (i%2==0):
            num = ord(message[i])
            num += 2
            encrypted = message[num]
        else:
            num = ord(message[i])
            num += 1
            encrypted = message[num]
    return encrypted

def decrypted(message):
    decrypted = ' '
    for i in message:
        if (i%2 == 0):
            num = ord(message[i])
            num -= 2
            decrypted = message[num]
        else:
            num = ord(message[i])
            num -= 1
            decrypted = message[num]
    return decrypted

def main():

message = str(input("Enter the message: "))
encrypted_msg = encrypted(message)
print("Encrypted message:", encrypted_msg)
decrypted_msg = decrypted(encrypted_msg)
print("Decrypted message:", decrypted_msg)
print("Original message:", message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**What I want to achieve:** This is the error coming. I want to encrypt and decrypt the characters based on their position in the message whether they are at odd places or even. what should I do?

```
if (i%2==0):
Error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `%` means something different when applied to a string than when applied to an integer.

Comment: `i` is a letter, you mean to check its index in the string. You probably want to use `enumerate()`.

Comment: It's not obvious that your encryption function is invertible. (At the very least, you want to *append* to `encrypted`, `encrypted += message[num]`.)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille enumerate() funtion is giving error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'enumerate' and 'int'.

Comment: @chepner I am having problem in getting odd and even places and edit those places in the string.

Comment: Yes, but even once you *do*, I'm not sure you can unambiguously decrypt the resulting message. It seem like two different characters in the same position could be mapped to the same character.

Comment: `enumerate` should be used this way: `for index, char in enumerate(message); if index % 2 == 0: num = ord(char) ...`. Note also that you probably meant `encrypted += message[num]` (mind the `+`), and take into consideration chepner's last comment.